# How to fetch this URL? Getting SSL handshake error

Tags: http, ubuntu, ssl, curl, https

I'm trying to fetch the following URL via various libraries and command-line tools, but running into a SSL handshake error.

```
> curl https://www.joelosteen.com/Views/RSS/Feed?t=PodcastVideo&ct=CustomList&cst=Podcasts
curl: (35) error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error
```

I've seen [here](https://razcx.wordpress.com/2013/02/19/curl-and-tomcat-ssl-routinesssl23_get_server_hellotlsv1-alert-internal-error/) it may be fixed by reducing possible ciphers, but trying [this less strict call](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/169428/36161) with restricted ciphers doesn't fix it.

```
curl -vlkL "https://www.joelosteen.com/Views/RSS/Feed?t=PodcastVideo&ct=CustomList&cst=Podcasts" --ciphers DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
```

Any ideas how I can fix this? It's a shared account, ie no root available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server supports only TLS version 1.2, i.e. no TLS 1.0 or even SSL 3.0. My guess is that the curl you use is simply too old to use TLS 1.2, but without further details about the version you use this guess can not be verified.

To determine the version of curl use `curl --version`. If you see it is compiled with OpenSSL than it should show at least version 1.0.1 of OpenSSL to have TLS 1.2 support.

> curl -vlkL ... --ciphers DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA

This is not a cipher supported by the server. One of the ciphers supported is AES128-SHA but again, no chance if your curl does not support TLS 1.2.

Comment: You're right. It's an old version. "curl 7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP". Apparently that's a 2011 model. I'll see if I can build a new one.

Comment: @mahemoff: This version has OpenSSL 1.0.1 which should include TLS 1.2 support. But some vendors (like Ubuntu) shipped OpenSSL 1.0.1 for a while with TLS 1.2 disabled on the client side, because there were some problems with some servers. It might be that you use such a stripped down OpenSSL version.

Comment: Thanks, it was an Ubuntu issue indeed. It came down to a lot of re-compiling OpenSSL + Curl and got this working in the end (https://askubuntu.com/questions/475670/how-to-build-curl-with-the-latest-openssl/582104#comment966406_582104).